# Kivy and Python TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, kivy

I have two files among other kivy files as shown below. When running the main file, I am getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\JeffO\OneDrive\Desktop\Gym App\workoutbanner.py", line 13, in __init__
    super(WorkoutBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JeffO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\gridlayout.py", line 279, in __init__
    super(GridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JeffO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 76, in __init__
    super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JeffO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 350, in __init__
    super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 245, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Can you help me figure out what is wrong? I am expecting to obtain a profile picture on the main screen. I suspect the left_image in the second file to cause the problem but I am not sure.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import requests
import json
from workoutbanner import WorkoutBanner


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior,Image):
    pass

class SigninScreen(Screen):
    pass

GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainApp(App):
    my_user_id = 'user1'
    user_table = "users"
    activity_table = "activities"
    def build(self):
        return GUI
    
    def on_start(self):
        #Query database data
        result_users = requests.get("https://uniquedatabase-c4647-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/" + self.user_table + ".json")
        result_activities = requests.get("https://uniquedatabase-c4647-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/" + self.activity_table + ".json")
        data_users = json.loads(result_users.content.decode())
        data_activities = json.loads(result_activities.content.decode())
        
        streak_label = self.root.ids['home_screen'].ids['streak_label']
        streak_label.text = str(data_users[self.my_user_id]['streak'])
        
        banner_grid = self.root.ids['home_screen'].ids['banner_grid']
        for workouts in data_activities.values():
            W = WorkoutBanner(user=workouts['user'])
            banner_grid.add_widget(W)
            
        
        #Fill HomeScreen feed
    def change_screen(self,screen_name):
        screen_manager = self.root.ids["screen_manager"]
        screen_manager.current = screen_name
        
MainApp().run()
```

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout 
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from firebase_functions import get_profile_picture
from datetime import datetime

class WorkoutBanner(GridLayout):
    
    rows = 1
  
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(WorkoutBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      
        left = FloatLayout()
        left_image = Image(source= "images/" + kwargs['user'], 
        size_hint =(1,0.8), pos_hint={"top":1,"left":1})
        
        left.add_widget(left_image)
        
        self.add_widget(left)
```

Answer (score 2):

The line of code:

```
W = WorkoutBanner(user=workouts['user'])
```

is providing a `kwargs` argument to `WorkoutBanner`, but your `__init__()` method of `WorkoutBanner` does not handle that `kwarg`. As a result, that `kwargs` is passed to the `super`:

```
super(WorkoutBanner, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

and that in turn passes the `kwargs` to its `super`. And so on until it reaches the `EventDispatcher.__init__()` where it causes an exception.

I believe you can fix that by just adding a `Property` to `WorkoutBanner` for the `user` attribute:

```
class WorkoutBanner(GridLayout):
    rows = 1
    user = StringProperty('')
```

This assumes that the `user` is a `String`.